# Storing Multiple Records via a RESTful API

Tags: php, api, oop, rest, laravel

I am building an app that takes input via restful interface. I have decided to accept JSON as the input for storing data.

I am expecting the request to look like:

```
{ meta:{soemdata:'here'}, data: [rec1, rec2, rec3] }
```

I have a controller, an object the handles the form data, and the model that does the specific CRUD for my app.

I am deliberating over whose job it is to process the data - especially if there is multiple records to process.

One one hand, the form object can check the integrity of the request and the make several calls to the model->create method.

eg. sudo

```
For Each Record
validate
Success: Pass record to model
Model->create
```

OR

Should I pass the entire recordset to the model.

eg. sudo

```
Form Class: Check Integrity
Model->Create(  All Records )
Model: loop and create.
```

Or somewhere between the two maybe?